# Permutation with repeated elements and partitioned spaces (can be left once blank)

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

I have some repeated elements and partitioned spaces:

```
# Elements
people = [0, 0, 1]
# Index
seats = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

The number of elements **cannot greater than** the number of index. If the number of elements is lower than the number of index, each type of index can  left **one** index as blank.

```
from collections import Counter


def _is_elem_valid(people, seats) -> bool:
    """Valid elements check."""
    counter = 0
    for seat, c in Counter(seats).items():
        if c > 1:
            counter += 1

    # "True" is valid.
    # In this case is 6 >= 3 >= 2.
    return len(seats) >= len(people) >= counter
```

Same type of index are **unordered** and **continuously**. Otherwise the rules are same as normal permutation.

So the results will show as follows:

```
# None represent blank seats.
# Sorry about PEP8.
# Actual elements: (filled to the length of index)
[0, 0, 1, None, None, None]

# Index:
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd']
# Correspond to normal index:
[[0], [0], [1], [1], [2], [3]]

# For all 'a'
[ 0,   0,   1,  None,None,None]
[ 0,   1,   0,  None,None,None]
# For all 'b'
[ 0,  None, 0,   1,  None,None]
[ 1,  None, 0,   0,  None,None]
# For 'c'
[ 0,  None, 1,  None, 0,  None]
[ 1,  None, 0,  None, 0,  None]
[ 0,  None, 0,  None, 1,  None]
# For 'd'
[ 0,  None, 1,  None,None, 0  ]
[ 1,  None, 0,  None,None, 0  ]
[ 0,  None, 0,  None,None, 1  ]
```

I'm not so familiar with permutation algorithm. Is there any efficient solution here?

Comment: It may be just that it's a bit late, but I have no idea what you're trying to achieve here...

Comment: It follows combination rule between same types of indexes, like 'a' or 'b'. Otherwise it follows permutation rule.

Comment: Do you think you could explain in more detail within the question? Perhaps add some simple concrete examples of the rules you have in mind?

Comment: I have corrected my question. I hope this will be more clear.